# Visualizing data in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

In the data set I am trying to make a bar graph on top 10 artists that have the highest number of songs in top 500 songs of all time. I have the result, however I am unable to visualize it. I need to make a bar graph of the output that I am getting from this code.
Can someone tell what code should I add to make a bar graph of the output.
I imported pandas, seaborn and matplot, just need help with the code.

```
counts = dict()
for artists in my_data['artist']:
    counts[artists] = counts.get(artists, 0) + 1

def keyfunction(k):
    return counts[k]

plt.figure(figsize = (10, 30))
plt.title("Greatest Artists of All Time")
data = dict()

for key in sorted(counts, key=keyfunction, reverse=True)[:10]:
    print(key, counts[key])
```

Need to make a bar plot of the following output

```
Elton John 18
The Beatles 16
Elvis Presley 12
The Jimi Hendrix Experience 12
The Four Tops 10
Muddy Waters 8
Sam Cooke 8
The Clash 8
U2 8
The Isley Brothers 8
```

Answer (score 1):

You may do it like this,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# I assumed your counts is a dictionary
counts = {
    "Elton John": 18,
    "The Beatles": 16,
    "Elvis Presley": 12,
    "The Jimi Hendrix Experience": 12,
    "The Four Tops": 10,
    "Muddy Waters": 8,
    "Sam Cooke": 8,
    "The Clash": 8,
    "U2": 8,
    "The Isley Brothers": 8
}

y_pos = np.arange(len(counts))

# Create bars
plt.bar(y_pos, counts.values())

# Create names on the x-axis
plt.xticks(y_pos, counts.keys())

# Show graphic
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way that I'd like to show. If you prefer Matplotlib go with the solution provided by @Burning Alcohol.

```
import pandas as pd
counts = {
    "Elton John": 18,
    "The Beatles": 16,
    "Elvis Presley": 12,
    "The Jimi Hendrix Experience": 12,
    "The Four Tops": 10,
    "Muddy Waters": 8,
    "Sam Cooke": 8,
    "The Clash": 8,
    "U2": 8,
    "The Isley Brothers": 8
}
```

Create a DataFrame from the dictionary.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([counts])
```

The following gives a barplot with a legend outside the box.

```
axes = df.plot.bar()
axes.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1,1))
```

Another way is to put the labels in the x-axis. We first transpose the DataFrame.

```
tdf = df.T.reset_index()
tdf.columns = ['Artist', 'Counts']
```

And finally the plot.

```
tdf.plot.bar(x='Artist', y='Counts')
```